# Black screen with GNU GRUB version 2.04 when i turn on my laptop

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, 20.04, gnu

**This question is different from the previous ones. So please go through it before flagging**

Few days back. I had a dual boot in my laptop (with ubuntu) which earlier had windows 10 only ["**Install Ubuntu alongside windows boot manager**" ].

Initially, it was working perfectly. When I turned on my laptop it gives me three options

1. Ubuntu
2. Advanced option for Ubuntu
3. Windows

I was able to switch to either of Ubuntu or Windows.

But for the last two days when I turn on my laptop, it opens a black screen showing

```
GNU GRUB version 2.04

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists
possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or
file completions.
```

When I type `exit`, I have three options again but this time

1. Ubuntu
2. Windows
3. Network

Windows work properly (what I mean is when I click on windows it logs in to Windows), but when I click on Ubuntu it redirects back to "GNU GRUB version 2.04"

System Configuration:

- Processor: |ntel(R) Corefl M) i7—9750H CPU @ 2.60GHz 2.59 GHz
- Installed memory (RAM): 8.00 GB (7.88 GB usable)
- System type: 64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
- **BIOS mode: UEFI**
- 1 TB SSD

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bad idea to reinstall Ubuntu, maybe an incorrect update of Ubuntu caused it. Create a live USB/DVD and boot it through BIOS settings.

Also suggested that Ubuntu File System should be in a separate drive than where Windows drive is, and also initialize a swap partition for Ubuntu, both of which are done during disk management of the installation process.

Comment: Hi, How to remove ubuntu?? As I Installed Ubuntu alongside windows boot manager.(i.e. its in c drive with windows) So, i cant directly delete it

Comment: Ok. But I also want to know which filesystem you used for the drive which contains the ubuntu and windows files. The only file-systems with which you can do it is FAT32. Do you know about it?

Comment: yes I burnt ubuntu in an 8 GB pen drive(FAT 32) using Rufus

Comment: Follow this video for installing ubuntu again: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MSVV_EoApdo

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu 20.04 again following same process as previous[what you did earlier] ( this will uninstall any previous installation of ubuntu)

but this time make sure that you update ubuntu & other software!. this will work perfectly!

You can see steps on how to install (in ubuntu website)